# How can a user instantly change a div's width using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, var

Here's how I thought I would kind of do it but this didn't work :

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
  var input = document.getElementById('userinput'),
  width = document.getElementById('thing');
  input.onkeyup = function() {
  width.innerHTML = input.value}
</script>


<input id="userinput">
<div id="thing">You can decide the width of this div>
```

And so the user would input something like 50% and the div would be 50% width.

Thanks

Comment: Since you tag the question with jquery http://api.jquery.com/width/ Not sure why you are doing with the innerHTML there

Comment: why would assigning a value to the innerHTML of an element change it's width attribute?

Comment: Yeah I was about to answer suggesting using jQuery's width(); command. if jQuery is an option, that would be the best way I think: http://jsfiddle.net/ee5y4nz9/

Comment: Yah, I'll have to see if jQuery is an option for this project, but this works great too. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```js
width.style.width = input.value;
```

Also note that the input can be modified in other ways than the keyboard, e.g. with the mouse. So better listen to `input` event.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('userinput'),
    width = document.getElementById('thing');
input.oninput = function() {
  width.style.width = input.value;
};
```

```css
#thing {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input id="userinput">
<div id="thing">You can decide the width of this div</div>
```